# How can I configure a widget that is in a different class?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, object-oriented-database

I need the buttons within LeftFrame to change its appearance when clicked. In the class AccOne, I tried to do `left_frame.acc1.config(releif='SUNKEN')`, but I get NameError: name 'left_frame' not defined. I tried making left_frame global, but no luck.

Here's the script.

```
class MainApp(Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)



        container = Frame(self)
        container.pack()

        container.rowconfigure(4, weight=1)
        container.columnconfigure(2, weight=1)

        right_frame = RightFrame(container, self)
        left_frame = LeftFrame(container, right_frame)

        left_frame.pack(side=LEFT)
        right_frame.pack()

class RightFrame(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller, *args, **kwargs):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)

        self.frames = {}
        for F in (Welcome, AccOne, AccTwo, AccThree, AccFour, AccFive):
            frame = F(self, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame

        self.show_frame(Welcome)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.grid(row=0, column=0)
        frame.tkraise()

class LeftFrame(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller, *args, **kwargs):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        acc1 = Button(self, text="Account 1", width=12, height=3, command=lambda: controller.show_frame(AccOne))
        acc1.pack()
```

I figured it would make sense to configure the button under `def show_frame(self,cont):` but I have no idea where to start since that method isn't under LeftFrame.

Answer (score 0):

When creating tkinter windows with classes, try and think about creating a 'widget tree', this being a path through which you can access all of your widgets. In this simple example, MainWindow and SubWindow can access all of eachother's widgets:

```
class MainWindow(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)

        # widget
        self.lbl = tk.Label(self, text='Title')
        self.lbl.pack()

        # create child window, as class attribute so it can access all
        # of the child's widgets
        self.child = SubWindow(self)
        self.child.pack()

        # access child's widgets
        self.child.btn.config(bg='red')


class SubWindow(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        # can use this attribute to move 'up the tree' and access
        # all of mainwindow's widgets
        self.parent = parent

        # widget
        self.btn = tk.Button(self, text='Press')
        self.btn.pack()

        # access parent's widgets
        self.parent.lbl.config(text='Changed')
```

**Things to change in your code**

Firstly, every time you create a widget that you might want to access later, assign it to a class variable. For example (this is part of the cause of your problem):

```
self.left_frame
self.acc1
```

*not*

```
left_frame
acc1
```

Secondly, make proper use of your parent and controller arguments. You're doing these, but you never use them or assign them to an atribute, so they may as well not be there. Assign them to a `self.parent` or `self.controller` attribute, so if you need to access them in a method later, you can.

I don't know exactly what you're trying to do and I can't see your AccOne class, but you should be able to find a way to access that button by making these changes.

Good luck!